# In Android Studio, the "Configure Image Asset" window shakes, and error: ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -.. is not an ancestor of ... /ic_lau

Tags: image, android-studio, assets, illegalargumentexception

In Android studio (version 4.1.2) I added a new product-flavor to an existing project. I created the app/src/MYAPP subdirectory in the IDE, and added this new product-flavor to the app's build.gradle, then I tried to create the new Image Asset, but the "Configure Image Asset" window just shakes, and on command-line there is a 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error' about:

`"ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -...... is not an ancestor of ...../ic_launcher-playstore.png`
(the full console error output is given below):

I've also ran the Build menu commands: 'clean project', build project, and installed latest version of gradle. I've tried importing different size images, and tried both png and jpeg, but no success.

This had worked okay when created a previous product-flavour.

This also occurred with Android studio 3.6 before I updated to 4.1.2 thinking that might fix this problem. I also updated to the latest gradle.

When I start Android studio from command-line, by using:

`/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

Then when I try to create new Image Asset, the following output is given (where I've replaced my username, project name, and app name with MYID, MYPROJECT_NAME, and MYAPP_NAME respectively):

````
2021-03-05 15:26:04,704 [ 130664]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - /Users/MYID/Documents/AndroidApps/MYPROJECT_NAME/app/src/main/MYAPP_NAME is not an ancestor of /Users/MYID/Documents/AndroidApps/MYPROJECT_NAME/app/src/main/ic_launcher-playstore.png
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /Users/MYID/Documents/AndroidApps/MYPROJECT_NAME/app/src/main/MYAPP_NAME is not an ancestor of /Users/MYID/Documents/AndroidApps/MYPROJECT_NAME/app/src/main/ic_launcher-playstore.png
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.wizard.ProposedFileTreeModel$Node$Companion.makeTree(ProposedFileTreeModel.kt:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.wizard.ProposedFileTreeModel.<init>(ProposedFileTreeModel.kt:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.lambda$onEntering$3(ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.java:444)
    at com.android.tools.idea.observable.ListenerManager.listenAndFire(ListenerManager.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.onEntering(ConfirmGenerateImagesStep.java:411)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:309)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$NextAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1819)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:912)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:844)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:708)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1644)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidAssetStudioAction.actionPerformed(AndroidAssetStudioAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:280)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:296)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:285)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:517)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:36)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:539)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:974)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:912)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:844)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:741)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:502)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2021-03-05 15:26:04,707 [ 130667]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1.2  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882
2021-03-05 15:26:04,708 [ 130668]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2021-03-05 15:26:04,708 [ 130668]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X
2021-03-05 15:26:04,709 [ 130669]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: NewAndroidImageAsset```
````

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a way around this problem:  On that "Configure Image Asset" window, the "Launcher Icons .." has an "Options" tab - setting the Generate "Google play store icon" to 'No' solved this problem (see attached screenshot). It won't generate the store icon, but will generate the rest of the icons.

[image]